# linq to compare the values between list<usertypeclass>and list<string>

Tags: c#, linq, list, class, xamarin.ios

i m new to LINQ 
and i want to write linq to fetch the value between  `list <usertypeclass>` and `list <string>`

i have a class

```
public class Hashtable 
        {
             public string Id
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
             public string MediaType 
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
             public string Href 
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

---

then i use this class to add values in list

```
var list = new List<Hashtable>
{
 new Hashtable { Id = "x001.xhtml", MediaType = "application/xhtm+xml", Href = "text/001.xhtml" },
 new Hashtable { Id = "x002.xhtml", MediaType = "application/xhtm+xml", Href = "text/002.xhtml" },
 new Hashtable { Id = "x003.xhtml", MediaType = "application/xhtm+xml", Href = "text/003.xhtml" }
};
```

---

i have another list which contains values like:

```
List<string> lstrhtml = new List<string>();
lstrhtml.Add("contents.xhtml");
lstrhtml.Add("x003.xhtml");
lstrhtml.Add("x002.xhtml");
lstrhtml.Add("x001.xhtml");
```

now i need to right linq to match the both list with id value i.e for e.g. x003.xhtml and extract href value,i tried so far is:

```
var val=list.Where(o=>lstrhtml.Contains(o["Id"].ToString()))
             .Select(o=>o["Href"]).ToList();
```

but it giving me error....please reply and suggest me where I'm going wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: Why is that class called Hashtable, when it has nothing to do with a hash-table. That is just adding confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a join:

```
var query = from id in lstrhtml
            join hashtable in list on id equals hashtable.Id
            select hashtable.href;

foreach (string href in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(href);
}
```

(Side-note: I'd personally avoid using the name `Hashtable` if possible, given that many readers will think of `System.Collections.Hashtable` when they see it.)

Comment: @shweta Note that LINQ joins usually fail on the device with "attempting to JIT-compile method..." messages. On the simulator they execute fine.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to do inner join between both the list will do task for you rather than contains

```
var query =
from h in listofHashtable
join s in lstrhtml 
on h.Id  equals s
select h.Href;
```